# Unparseable data exception

Tags: java

I want to transform this data: "Thu, 06 Sep 2012 16:15:00 +0200" in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm

this is my code:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat rssFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
public static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = rssFormat.parse(pubDate);
date.setHours(date.getHours()+2); //this is for gmt difference
this.pubDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

it seems ok...why does it throw this exception?

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 04 Sep 2012 16:45:00 +0200"
```

Comment: Please send value of `pubDate`. The problem is that id does not suite the format your wrote.

Comment: What exception? Please print the whole stack trace.

Comment: `date.getHours()` ? What kind of `Date` object do you use ? Deprecated in java.sql.Date since 1.4.2

Comment: It is working for me. No exceptions.

Comment: @AlexR pubDate is just a string attribute, my yyyy-MM-etc formatted date is saved there.

Comment: This is Working for me. which time zone you are in ?

Comment: Which java version are you using ? (and yes using "Thu, 06 Sep 2012 16:15:00 +0200" as pubDate this did not throw an exception.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me - but then, I'm in a locale where "Thu" is a valid day abbreviation, and "Sep" is  a valid month abbreviation. Perhaps you aren't? Assuming you know you *will* be getting US-English day/month names, you should specify that. Try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
```

Note that you *absolutely* should not be calling `Date.setHours` and `Date.getHours` like this. Those methods have both been deprecated for over 15 years.

Instead, you should be formatting with a `SimpleDateFormat` set into an appropriate time zone... or preferrably, you should use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) in the first place, which is a much more pleasant date/time API.

Comment: You're right! As I am in Italy Thu and Sep were not valid!  As for date matter I'll switch to calendar, will it be ok?